# clear message that came from php GET

Tags: javascript, php, html

Let me clarify.

I have an HTML form for sending e-mails in a file named `contact.php`

On the server side I have this in php, after the e-mail is sended

```
header('Location:contact.php?co=1'); exit();
```

And on the client side (in the same file that contains the form)

```
if ($_GET['co']) {
    echo 'We got it!';          
    }
```

So the user knows if the mail is sended.

How can I clear that message, the "We got it"?

I want to make something like

```
<input name="mail" type="email"  onFocus="cleatThemessage" ><br>
```

so when the user clicks on a field in the form, the message goes away.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use jQuery at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work for you:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['co']) {
        echo '<div id="message">We got it!</div>';          
    }
?>

<input name="mail" type="email"  onFocus="document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = '' ;" ><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Before `header('Location:contact.php?co=1'); exit();`

Add

```
$_SESSION['notification'] = "We got it";
```

And change,

```
if ($_GET['co']) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['notification']) && $_SESSION['notification'] != '') {
        echo $_SESSION['notification'];
        unset($_SESSION['notification']);
    }          
}
```

For this to work I am assuming your form submits to a page say saveContact.php and after insert into database query you redirect it to contact.php?co=1 such that `$_SESSION['notification'] = 'We got it'` executes only once after the insert into database query.

Comment: These are also called as 'session based flash messages', google it to find more ways to achieve same.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

**Html**

```
<input name="mail" type="email"  onFocus="clearThemessage(this)" ><br>
```

**Javascript**

```
function clearTheMessage(element) {
   element.value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['co'])){
    echo '<p id="gotit">We got it!</p>';
}?>

<input name="mail" type="email"  onFocus="removeMessage()" >

<script type="text/javascript">
function removeMessage(){
    var el = document.getElementById('gotit');
    if(typeof(el) != 'undefined' && el != null){
        el.remove();
    }
}
</script>
```